# Add class only for mobile

Tags: html, css

I want to add the class `p-5` only for mobile environment.

for pc

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">`

for mobile

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light p-5" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">`

I know there is something like to switch css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
```

However class `p-5` is blackbox for me because it is bootstrap default class.

So how should I make it??

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If so tag your question with it

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/), you can also add a breakpoint to it: `{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}`

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can add classes using CSS alone. You could it theory use media screen and change the attributes for a class and that would be fine as well. You can use jQuery to do what you want easily.
A way to do this is to attach the resize event like so :

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if($(window).height() > 768px) {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('p-5');
  }else{
    $('.navbar').addClass('p-5');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to control the padding using only bootstrap padding utility classes:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light p-5 p-sm-0"
```